# Launch Flask in a Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

I try to call a method as thread then call another method while the StartServer method is background runing but when self.Thread.run() is executed, the code is stuck. Any ideas ? I try to put start server in another class, in a outside function but I still have that issue.

```
import time
import webview
import threading
from flask import Flask

class Windows:

    def __init__(self, EntryPoint = "index.html"):

        self.EntryPointContent = self.ReadPage(EntryPoint)

        self.Thread = threading.Thread(target = self.StartServer)
        self.Thread.daemon = True
        self.Thread.run()
        
        self.ShowWindows()

    def StartServer(self):

        app = Flask(__name__)
        app.debug = False
        app.reloader = False

        @app.route("/")
        def root():
            return self.EntryPointContent

        app.run()


    def ReadPage(self, FileName):

        File = open(FileName, "r")
        return File.read()


    def ShowWindows(self):

        webview.create_window("Hey !", "http://localhost:5000")
        webview.start()

app = Windows(EntryPoint="page.html")
```

Comment: Try calling the class from a new thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Thread.run()`, call `Thread.start()`. Run will just call your `StartServer` method on the current thread. Below is a short example so you can try this out.

```
import threading
from time import sleep


def l(msg):
    while True:
        print(msg)
        sleep(1)


thread = threading.Thread(target=lambda: l('foo'))
thread.start() # swap with thread.run()

l('bar')
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that

```
app.reloader = False
```

isn't doing what you hope it to. Instead, try

```
app.run(use_reloader=False)
```